# Proportional Scaling of Images in a Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML table with a width of 100%. The Table has two rows and with two cells each.
Each cell contains the same Image with width=100% and height=auto. So the Image Scales proportional inside the Cell.

Here is the HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://idevicegazette.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/htc-one-sample-002-200x200.jpg" />
            <div class="info"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://idevicegazette.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/htc-one-sample-002-200x200.jpg" />
            <div class="info"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://idevicegazette.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/htc-one-sample-002-200x200.jpg" />
            <div class="info"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://idevicegazette.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/htc-one-sample-002-200x200.jpg" />
            <div class="info"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And Here the CSS:

```
table
{
    width: 100%;
}

table td
{
    width: 50%;
    position relative;
}

img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

To describe the problem I've setup a jsfiddle (best use chrome):

http://jsfiddle.net/Fk8vQ/3/

If you start changing the size of the result window you will see that there are situations
where the Images in the right column are 1 Pixel smaller than those in the left column.
The goal is that all Images always have the exakt same size (the image in the second column should have the same width/height as the image on the right side).

I'm aware that Problem is issued always then when the table width is an odd pixel number which dosnt allow the two images be exakt the same size. I'm searching for somekind of a workaround to this Problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could force the table width to always be an even number.
Something roughly like this

```
width = window.innerWidth;
if( width % 2 != 0 ){
    width -= 1;
}

document.getElementById("tableId").width = width;
```

Of course you would have to accept some slight assymetry when the window width is an odd number.